# How to find out what this error is about?

Tags: 16.04

How to find out what this error is about? `Details Action` doesn't show any specific information.
[image]

Comment: It is normal bug reporting process with [Apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport). Just click *Report problem* and it may show bug-reporting window with details (but sometimes this window is not shown as you note). Otherwise look at new files in `/var/crash` as @user535733 said.

Comment: It might help to describe what you were doing at the time. This link might help you understand apport and what it does: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/disable-apport-error-reporting-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apport saves it's work in `/var/crash` - look for new files there.

Open those files in a text editor (like gedit) to read what apport discovered.

Apport is a problem-reporting application - it's typically triggered when *something else* crashes.